# Why does Spy++ fail with console windows

Tags: winapi, windows-console, windows-messages, spy++

I was attempting to verify that messages were being sent to my window using Spy++ (running Windows 7), but I mistakingly tried to spy on a console window that my program was using for debug output.  Spy++ promptly notified me that "The specified window cannot be spied upon. Windows will not allow access to the message stream for this window."

While Spy++ does correctly gather other information about the window (e.x. name, style, class name), it cannot process the message queue.  Why is this?  And, out of morbid curiosity, is there a way to prevent Spy++ from accessing the message queue of my own custom window using the Windows API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While Spy++ does correctly gather other information about the window (e.x. name, style, class name), it cannot process the message queue. Why is this?

The console window belongs to the [CSRSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem) process, not the CMD.EXE process.  CSRSS is a critical system service that is protected and cannot be hooked without special debug privileges.

"*When a user-mode process calls a function involving **console windows**, process/thread creation, or side-by-side support, instead of issuing a system call, **the Win32 libraries (kernel32.dll, user32.dll, gdi32.dll) send an inter-process call to the CSRSS process** which does most of the actual work without compromising the kernel.*"

> And, out of morbid curiosity, is there a way to prevent Spy++ from accessing the message queue of my own custom window using the Windows API?

Typically, no. Unless you manage to run your window in a protected system process.

Comment: You've piqued my curiosity. After reading more about this on Wikipedia, I discovered the secondary mechanism, conhost.exe (spawned by CSRSS under the current user account) is used to display the console window.  Seems like a process running under the user account would be fair game to Spy++, but then again, the desktop window is also denied spying.  Is it the method in which CreateProcess is called that prevents Spy++ from working?

Comment: @BrianDavis: The Desktop window is not treated in any special way, and Spy++ can be used to monitor messages. Are you perhaps using Spy++ with the wrong bitness (e.g. 32-bit Spy++ on a 64-bit OS)?

Answer (score 0):

So, I discovered this myself recently, I created a console .NET application which launches a process using CMD.EXE and I ran into an issue with some Win32 interop around the keyboard. So I broke out the previously trusty Spy++ utility to see what was happening to find that I was completely unable to monitor the message queue for my application from it.

So as per the op's question:

"*Is there a way to prevent Spy++ from accessing the message queue of my own custom window using the Windows API?*"

There is a list of restricted windows classes baked into Spy++:

- SpyxxHk (presumably it's own hooking class),
- #32768 (Context Menu),
- #32769 (the Desktop),
- ttyGrab ,
- ConsoleWindowClass (Command Prompt)

So, if you in any way tie your app to these classes Spy++ will display that block message when attempting to watch their messages, of course this may not prove useful since it only restricts those classes.

Referring to MS documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx

"For out-of-context events, the event is delivered on the same thread that called SetWinEventHook. In some situations, even if you request WINEVENT_INCONTEXT events, the events will still be delivered out-of-context. These scenarios include **events from console windows** and events from processes that have a different bit-depth (64 bit versus 32 bits)"

Suggests it is possible to get console window events.